# How to deal with Java warning popup?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While running WebDriver automation scripts I came across a situation where it is trying to open a page which contain one segment with live camera (Made with Java applet). Once script reaches to this page - a Security Warning alert (with allow and not allow) shows up and blocks the execution process. Is this something that anyone faced before - actually I am looking for an option to block this security warning to get displayed on the page.

A popup is coming where i want to click on the "Allow". How to move the focus to the new popup window and click on Allow.

Can anyone please help me for the above problem?

Comment: You can handle this using alert api. Use driver.switchTo().alert().accept. This will mimic clicking on ok button.

Comment: I don't think a Java popup can be handled by the Alert API. This will most likely fail. Unfortunately, Selenium can't handle it, you'll need to try some other tool - the most crude being the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, the more advanced being e.g. [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/).

Comment: You can use Java's ROBOT class and click on the pop-up.

Comment: In control pane there is Java Control Panel -> i think there was advanced tab where you could set options. I think it was Mixed code verification.

Comment: Hi Erki,

In the Advanced tab, there are many four radio buttons. Which one i should select?

Comment: be aware, that once you leave the delegation of the webbrowser, (for example a java applet, flash object, or silverlight) you are unable to operate with it.  I'd call this an invalid test.  The test that you should have, is "verify that this java applet tag exists"

Comment: I tried with the below code using Robot class and unable to do it. Alert aa = driver.switchTo().alert(); // Trying to switch to the warning popup window
            
            Robot robot = new Robot();
             
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT); 
            
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
            
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

Answer (score 7):

I was having problems accepting the java applet "Allow"

My solution was to create a firefox profile that had the settings to always activate the plugin:

```
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();

fp.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates( true );

fp.setPreference( "security.enable_java", true ); 

fp.setPreference( "plugin.state.java", 2 );

WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver( fp );
```

Where plugin.state.java:

```
plugin.state.java = 0 --> never activate
plugin.state.java = 1 --> ask to activate
plugin.state.java = 2 --> always activate
```

This might get you closer...

Answer (score 0):

Selenium uses a different firefox profile because Java was inactive for me and I did not have my firebug plugin in the Firefox browser Selenium launched. I would have to open another Firefox to use Firebug.

I found my default Firefox profile by searching %appdata% in the start menu then clicking on Roaming/ Mozilla/ Firefox/ Profile/ and then it gave my default profile name.

You can also open the firefox help menu (? logo) & click troubleshoot info... click Show Profile Folder

I then configured selenium to use my default profile so Java was enabled and Firebug was available in the browser Selenium launched:

Make sure that you use "/" in selenium even though it may use "\" in the windows  path location

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/41s7nq9o.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get('www.stackoverflow.com')
```

where 41s7nq9o.default is the name of your default profile